# How to include assets (JS) into the layout from a controller - CakePHP

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

This is probably a duplicate, but I am struggling to find the same question and certainly the answer.

I'm a little unsure and confused on how assets are handled in Cake (2).  I want to include some JS on a specific page, not on every page of the app, so I would assume I would need to add that to my controller method?  I can't find how I would do that.  The close I have come is the JsHelper, but that seems more for constructing JS using PHP rather than just loading an assets.

I am well aware I can do `$this->Html->script('script')`, but this does not work in the controller, only in the view.

Although not needed right now, it would also be useful to be able to pass variables through to the included JavaScript.  A good example of this may be an AJAX request on an 'edit' screen for something: `$.ajax({ url: "/pages/edit_ajax/<?= $page->id ?>" });`

Any help is gladly received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this you will want to use [Blocks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks) (providing you are in v2.1+).

In your **layout** file you will no doubt have a line `$this->fetch('script')` which will go find the `script` block and output it into your layout.

Next, in the view for the **Controller action**, let's say `index()` you will have a matching view `index.ctp`. In this view you can append your script to the `script` block.

So in the view,

```
<?php $this->append('script'); // we want to append to the script block ?>
<script>
$(function() {
  alert('Hey there, Im only on this page!');
})
</script>
<?php $this->end();?>
```

When you visit your controller action you will see that this will be output, hopefully at the bottom of your page, along with your other javascript.

As you've appended the script in the view, it will only ever execute when this view is loaded.

In regard to your second question, you can just set variables to the view in your controller, and then echo them into your javascript.

```
// Controller
$this->set('jsVar', 'JavascriptInBlocks');

// View
<?php $this->append('script'); // we want to append to the script block ?>
<script>
$(function() {
  alert('Hey there <?php echo $jsVar;?>');
})
</script>
<?php $this->end();?>
```